# Replacing ID with another will degrade performance in Solr?

Tags: performance, solr, indexing, unique-key

I am using **Solr 4.10.2**. I have build **indexed** documents. In **Schema.xml**, I have removed **ID** field and replaced it with **ngram** field and made **ngram** field as **unique key**.

I have a question - when I will do **search** query on Solr. Will the **performance** of searching **harm**? And also it will affect D**ocument caching**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ngram field as a unique key is a very bad idea. The unique key field must not be a "tokenized" type otherwise multiple individual tokens comprise a key which will lead to false positive matches. You should use a string or an int/long field type only as the type of a unique key.

Of course, performance is also affected somewhat because ngram fields create many tokens instead of one, but that'd be negligible compared to the other problems such as false positives and duplicate documents.

Comment: I have not used ngram field. ngram is only a name to the field and its field type is string. You are examining the question in wrong way. So, tell me will it degrade the performance

Comment: No, using any other string field doesn't matter. The performance is the same regardless of what the uniqueKey field is called.

Comment: I am extremely sorry `@Shalin`. Actually, my ngram field is not string type. I have defined my own fieldType="textSpell" which contains 2 lines `<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>` & `<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" minShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true"/>`. Now, Plz tell me will it degrade the performance ?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it will impact Solr performance. As you are defining your own field as uniqueKey so it will index documents based on given key. I have used same approch for one of my project where we are using documentId as uniqueKey.

Comment: Ok. You are sure. How much of data you indexed? How much of time, it takes to retrieve the documents which u searched?

Comment: I have indexed 6K documents, where each document contains 400 fields. Retrieve query usually depends on your query. If you search in all indexed data then it took milliseconds.

Comment: I have indexed 1 Lakh documents where each document has 2 fields only. When I searched a word into indexed data at first time, it takes approx 2 seconds. Next time, when I searched the same query, it takes millisecond because that time, documents kept into cache. That's why. **Have you use any technique to search query?**